# How to find a easy way to check date sequences for a lot of date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which record things happen time as below

[image: table]

each thing will go though all this 5 steps, start->first try->second try->third try->end., and I need to test if the time is reasonable.

Rules as below:

- if one thing have gone to a step then every record before should not be empty.(intergrity)
- date should be bigger step by step

Now, I can choose to wirte the rules in SQL or dax, but the methods I've come up with are complicated, just like:

```
case when 
    end_time is not null and (first_time is null or second_time  is null or third_time is null or start_time is null )
    then 'things end, some before date missing'
    when third_time  is not null and (first_time is null or second_time  is null or start_time is null  )
    then 'third try done, some before date missing' 
    ...
    end check_integrity
```

second rule seems more complex. Is there a easy way to check if (date1, date2,...,date-n) follow the sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Possible table structure (MySQL 8+ needed):

```sql
CREATE TABLE things (
    things INT PRIMARY KEY,
    start_time DATE,
    first_try_time DATE,
    second_try_time DATE,
    third_try_time DATE,
    end_time DATE,
    CHECK (first_try_time IS NULL OR (first_try_time > start_time AND start_time IS NOT NULL)),
    CHECK (second_try_time IS NULL OR (second_try_time > first_try_time AND first_try_time IS NOT NULL)),
    CHECK (third_try_time IS NULL OR (third_try_time > second_try_time AND second_try_time IS NOT NULL)),
    CHECK (end_time IS NULL OR (end_time > third_try_time AND third_try_time IS NOT NULL))
);
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SpPfRFCR)